# 413: Requested Entity too large, PHP File Upload

Tags: php, ajax, file, nginx, upload

I have a problem with uploading PDF File of size 1.25mb to server folder using AJAX Request from a PHP File. My Nginx.conf also consists `client_max_body_size 100M` and my `php.ini` has `upload_max_filesize = 100M` and `post_max_size = 100M`.

[image]

Comment: did you restart nginx and php-fpm services after modifying the configurations?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted and Reloaded the server and fpm

Comment: Please increase post_max_size. It should be greater than the upload_max_filesize

Comment: Tried it also .